# how to set the number of features to use in random selection sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I am using sklearn RandomForest Classifier/Bag classifier for learning and I am not getting the expected results when compared to Java/Weka Machine Learning library. 
In Weka, I am learning the model with - Random forest of 10 trees, each constructed while considering 6 random features. (setNumFeatures need to be set and default is 10 trees)

In sklearn - I am not sure how to specify the number of features to randomly consider while constructing a random forest of 10 trees. This what I am doing:

```
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=num_trees, max_features=6)
rf_classifier = rf_classifier.fit(train_file, train_file_label)
for items in rf_classifier.estimators_:
    classifier_list.append(items)
```

I saw the docs and there is a parameter - max_features but I am not sure if that serves the purpose. I get this error when I am trying to calculate entropy:

```
# code to calculate voting entropy for all features (unlabeled data)
vote_count_for_features = list(classifier_list[0].predict(feature_data_arr))
for i in range(1, len(classifier_list)):
    res_temp = []
    res_temp = list(classifier_list[i].predict(feature_data_arr))
    vote_count_for_features = [x + y for x, y in zip(vote_count_for_features, res_temp)]
```

If I set that parameter to 6, than my code fails with the error message:

> Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features
>   is 6 and input n_features is 31

Inputs: Sample set of 1 million records with 31 features. When I run weka, the number of rules extracted are around 1000 whereas when I run the same thing through sklearn - I get hardly 70 rules.

I am new to python and sklearn and I am trying to figure out where am I doing wrong. (Weka code has been tested well and gives 95% precision, 80% recall - so I am assuming that's good)

Note: I have used sklearn imputer to impute missing values using 'mean' strategy whereas Weka has ways to handle NaN.

This is what I am trying to achieve: Learn Random Forest on a sample set, extract rules, evaluate rules and then apply on the bigger set

Any suggestions or input will really help me debug through the issue and solve it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the individual trees get confused since they only use 6 features, but you give them 31. You can try to get the prediction to work by setting `check_input = False`:

```
 list(classifier_list[i].predict(feature_data_arr, check_input = False))
```